# 16.04 login screen freeze on waking up after suspend [lenovo e31-70]

Tags: 16.04, suspend, intel-graphics, freeze

ubuntu 16.04 sometimes freezes on waking up after suspend.

Additional details:

1. sometimes screen freezes completely, sometimes not and I'm able to move mouse
2. password input always disabled (no cursor) and if I blindly input password and press Enter nothing happens
3. sometimes (when freeze is not complete) when I'm trying to change language (in my case Shift + Alt) screen flickers to desktop and there "ubuntu error" message box is shown, but it rapidly switches back to login screen
4. sometimes laptop waking up without problem (very rarely, but it doesn't correlate with time of being suspend!)

Are there any ways to fix it? Sometimes I experienced black screen on waking up with ubuntu 14.04 (but very rarely), but I've never met black screen stuck with ubuntu 16.04. I've tried to upgrade linux-header/kernel etc. but it didn't help (now its  version is 4.6).

I went from 14.40 to 16.04 via clean install (only /home was saved).

My graphics card is Intel HD Graphics 5500.

I'm ready to put here any additional info.

Comment: There are a lot of problems related with that. It's something about the driver, but this is more common with AMD Radeon cards. My Dell notebook have two vgas, one Intel Graphics 5500 and a Radeon R7 M265